# Why is bundle install (when using capistrano) creating a capistrano folder for gems?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I'm totally lost with the working of capistrano and bundler together. I've just started using capistrano for my deployment, and when I'm trying to run "bundle install" on my local development machine, bundler is actually creating a "capistrano" folder and installing the gems there. Ideally before capifying my project, "bundle install" would just pick up the system gems and worked like a charm.

This has been bothering my for some time, and I want to understand why this is happening, and how to prevent it (atleast on my local development machine). I understand that this might be useful when actually doing a "cap deploy" on the production server, but why in development ??

Help..point in the right direction someone please..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you are doing this

```
bundle install capistrano
```

Just,

```
bundle install
```

should be enough if you have included capistrano to your Gemfile

Comment: Hey @Aditya ...nope I'm just doing the plain old bundle install inside my app..and the best part is..it's not generating any gemfile.lock (i renamed it to gemfile.bak just to check what's happening)...very strange..

Comment: I'd just delete the capistrano directory as well as the .bundle directory with a config file in it and restart. This can happen when you have previously (by error done bundle install capistrano) earlier.

Comment: yeah...that's right...my bundle config had the path as the "capistrano" folder..so I would have done bundle install capistrano earlier at some point of time...siighh...what a waste of time !..Thanks @Aditya..